# mportError: PILKit was unable to import the Python Imaging Library. Please confirm it`s installed and available on your current Python path

Tags: python, django, debian, python-imaging-library

everyone. I home some problem. I have django project. The project use django-imagekit. If I run app with help command: python3 manage.py runserver - all works! BUT! If I use mod_wsgi I get it:

```
root@twingo:/home/evgen/twingo/build/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages# tail /var/log/apache2/error.log 
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268235 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535]     from .registry import register
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268259 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535]   File "/home/evgen/twingo/build/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/imagekit/registry.py", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268388 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535]     from .utils import autodiscover, call_strategy_method
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268414 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535]   File "/home/evgen/twingo/build/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/imagekit/utils.py", line 14, in <module>
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268550 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535]     from pilkit.utils import *
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268574 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535]   File "/home/evgen/twingo/build/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pilkit/utils.py", line 6, in <module>
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268752 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535]     from .lib import Image, ImageFile, StringIO, string_types
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268778 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535]   File "/home/evgen/twingo/build/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pilkit/lib.py", line 19, in <module>
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268859 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535]     raise ImportError('PILKit was unable to import the Python Imaging Library. Please confirm it`s installed and available on your current Python path.')
[Fri Jun 19 21:13:25.268898 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20907] [remote 91.238.231.242:65535] ImportError: PILKit was unable to import the Python Imaging Library. Please confirm it`s installed and available on your current Python path.
root@twingo:/home/evgen/twingo/build/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages#
```

### Here my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        WSGIDaemonProcess twingo python-path=/home/evgen/twingo/build/:/home/evgen/twingo/build/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
        WSGIProcessGroup twingo
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/evgen/twingo/build/wsgi.py
        Alias /robots.txt /home/evgen/twingo/build/robots.txt
        Alias /favicon.ico /home/evgen/twingo/build/static/images/favicon.ico

    Alias /media/ /home/evgen/twingo/build/media/
    Alias /static/ /home/evgen/twingo/build/static/

    <Directory /home/evgen/twingo/build/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/evgen/twingo/build/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>


    <Directory /home/evgen/twingo/build/>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                   Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
```

### Here listing project dir:

```
root@twingo:/home/evgen/twingo/build# ls
authapp  env  feedback  manage.py  service  static  templates  travels  twingo  users  wsgi.py
```

### Here listing site-packages dir:

```
root@twingo:/home/evgen/twingo/build/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages# ls
Django-1.8.2.dist-info       django_appconf-1.0.1.dist-info    password_reset        six-1.9.0.dist-info
PIL              django_compress-1.0.1-py3.4.egg-info  pilkit            six.py
Pillow-2.8.2-py3.4.egg-info  django_imagekit-3.2.6-py3.4.egg-info  pilkit-1.1.12-py3.4.egg-info  tests
__pycache__          django_password_reset-0.7.dist-info   pip               utils
_markerlib           easy_install.py               pip-1.5.6.dist-info       utils-0.8.0-py3.4.egg-info
appconf              image                 pkg_resources
compress             image-1.4.0-py3.4.egg-info        setuptools
django               imagekit                  setuptools-17.0.dist-info
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: For a start, is your mod_wsgi actually compiled for Python 3.4? See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use

Comment: I just install libapache2-mod-wsgi

Comment: Which would usually be a Python 2.7 version. You would want libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 for a Debian/Ubuntu system. You would still want to check whether that is Python 3.3 or 3.4 as per the links. If you aren't using the system Python 3.4 but your own compiled Python installation then risk the system one could be 3.3. If using your own Python installation you should be install mod_wsgi yourself, compiled against your specific Python installation.

Comment: Problem not with mod_wsgi. Because if I not use imagekit all works.

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot mix a Python virtual environment built with one Python version, with mod_wsgi compiled for a different Python version. Any C extension modules in the Python virtual environment will be incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing Pillow

```
pip install Pillow
```